# Wireshark - Lua Dissector, detect which endpoint opened the connection?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a dissector for a protocol that I have to work with. This protocol runs atop TCP and is stateful.

In order to dissect the fields correctly, I need to identify which endpoint opened the TCP connection (the client).

Is there a way to get this info from the tcp dissector? Would I have to write a tap? I'm not so clear on how to do this in lua.

Cross posted on the Wireshark stack site [here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/5746/tcp-dissector-detect-which-endpoint-opened-the-connection).

Answer (score 1):

To write stateful protocol dissector in Lua you can use closures to store state information. 
you can easily decipher which endpoint started conversation if you analyse flags SYN/SYN+ACK for the first packets of given TCP stream # (which is generated by TCP dissector).

To make this work you should install a post dissector and check for 'tcp.stream' field.

You can checkout that technique in sources of my small [Lua wireshark dissector to capture HTTP state information](https://github.com/shomeax/wireshark-http-extra)